# The following error results when I try to sync Gradle Files:ERROR: Failed to resolve: android.recyclerview:recyclerview: Affected Modules: app

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-recyclerview, dependencies, androidx

So my Android Studio failed to resolve RecyclerView. I am new to android dev so please feel free to provide any input you find useful. I am not sure if it's a mistake I am making in repositories or if it's a version error.

app gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hasanat"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'android.recyclerview:recyclerview::1.1.0'
//AndroidX
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha03'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha03'

}
```

build gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()

 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ignore this. I made a version issue in recycler view.